# Do some regex on a 50GB file in perl

Tags: regex, perl

How can I stream a 50GB large file in perl to execute some regex for each line (or chunk)? I have tried with plain vanilla

```
for $line (<FH>) {
   # do regex
}
```

I have also tried Tie::File and File::Stream, but perl always tries to load the whole file into memory which is simply not possible.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use IO::Handle;
use Tie::File;
use File::Stream;
#tie @array, 'Tie::File', $ARGV[0] or die "could not open file";

STDOUT->autoflush(1);

$file=$ARGV[0];
open(INFO, "< $file") or die("Could not open  file.");

print "opening ... \n";
my $stream = File::Stream->new(<INFO>);

#$out = $ARGV[1];
#open(my $OH, '>', $out) or die "Could not open file '$out' $!";
print "starting ... \n";
while (<$stream>)  {
    $line = $_;
    $line =~ s/\n/\[!BR!\]/g;
    $line =~ s/<page>/\n<page>/g;
    $line =~ s/<\/page>/<\/page>\n/g;
    print $line;

    #STDOUT->flush();
}

close(INFO);
```

Comment: Did you check this page: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=956620 ? `open my $filehandle, '<', 'myfile.txt'; my $line_number = 0; while (defined($line = <$filehandle>)) { ... }` (no newlines in comments, sorry :()

Comment: @stribizhev no but you are right this works:`open my $filehandle, '<', 'myfile.txt';
while (defined($line = <$filehandle>)) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to use the approach outlined on this [PerlMonks page](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=956620).

Here is an example from that page:

```
# Set the character which will be used to indicate the end of a line.
# This defaults to the system's end of line character, but it doesn't
# hurt to set it explicitly, just in case some other part of your code
# has altered it from the default.
local $/ = "\n";

# Open the file for read access:
open my $filehandle, '<', 'myfile.txt';

my $line_number = 0;

# Loop through each line:
while (defined($line = <$filehandle>))
{
  # The text of the line, including the linebreak
  # is now in the variable $line.

  # Keep track of line numbers
  $line_number++;

  # Strip the linebreak character at the end.
  chomp $line;

  # Do something with the line.
  do_something($line);

  # Perhaps bail out of the loop
  if ($line =~ m/^ERROR/)
  {
    warn "Error on line $line_number - skipping rest of file";
    last;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**: To obtain the line number, you can omit `$line_number` and just use `$.` (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't `$.` give you the current line number?

Comment: @SeanBright: Sure - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Isn't `defined` a moot point in your while loop? The `while` will break if `undef` anyway.

Answer (score 9):

The correct "plain vanilla" syntax is

```
while (my $line = <FH>) { ...
```

Your `for` loop would indeed cause Perl to read the whole file into memory first.

Comment: Your last line is the critical point of relevance to the OP. `for` and `while` look very similar for file iterating, but the former reads the whole file in advance, where the latter does not.